# Return attributes within given radius of observation in R

Tags: r, coordinates, spatial, r-sp

Novice R programmer struggling to add a spatial component to large data set (>1500 obs)

Given a list of: observations, corresponding x/y points (not lat/long), and attributes; how can I write an algorithm to return the sum of variable "Z" for all observations within a given radius (10) of the observation in question. I need to do this for each observation.

Simplified data headers read as follows:

```
OBS      X        Y          Z**
A       56.55     -289.65  
B       52.59     -287.82   
C       58.34     -284.58
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The key is to use `mapply()` to *apply* a function to *m*ultiple vectors at a time - here: the X and Y components of your `data.frame`. Which function? One that adds the `Z` variable for all observations in your `data.frame` that are at most `radius` away from the "anchor point" (which we run over all entries).

```
> set.seed(1)
> foo <- data.frame(X=runif(100),Y=runif(100),Z=runif(100))
> radius <- 0.5
> result <- mapply(function(X,Y,Z)
    sum(foo$Z[(foo$X-X)^2+(foo$Y-Y)^2<=radius^2]),foo$X,foo$Y)
> head(cbind(foo,result))
          X         Y         Z   result
1 0.2655087 0.6547239 0.2675082 24.99153
2 0.3721239 0.3531973 0.2186453 30.51512
3 0.5728534 0.2702601 0.5167968 28.15519
4 0.9082078 0.9926841 0.2689506 12.10058
5 0.2016819 0.6334933 0.1811683 22.50695
6 0.8983897 0.2132081 0.5185761 19.05273
```

Note that of course each point's `Z` itself is counted in its radius. If you don't want that, you'll need to subtract `foo$Z`.

Look at `?mapply`.

Comment: It looks like this just counts the number of neighbours to each point. I think the question asks for a sum of a third variable Z over the neighbouring points. Maybe the OP can clarify whether this really answers the question.

Comment: Ege you are correct, the count is not enough, I need to sum "Z". 

This data set is forestry related and deals with competition induced by neighboring trees. "Z" is the basal area of trees, because larger neighboring trees exert more competition than smaller trees, the count will be insufficient.